# git push is failing - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, ssh, gerrit

I have a gerrit server with multiple repos.

in the manifest i am using  the `https://url` and it works fine for fetching.

i set a `sshl pushurl="ssh://ssh-dns-name:29418"` (note no username as part of this).

When i do the sync all the projects have remotes like -

```
origin  https://url/my_project  (fetch)
origin ssh://ssh-dns-name:2941/my_project (push)
```

now, when i do push, the git is complaining that Permission denied (publickey)!!!

i see that the user.name and user.email are setup properly.
`user.name "Abhayadev S"` (whic is setup in gerrit as user Full name)
and `user.email "abhayadevs...@in.com"` which is setup in gerrit as user email

also my client machine login name is "abhayadevs" which is the gerrit username.

if i use the username in the pushurl (`ssh://abhayadevs@ssh-dns-name:29418`), everything is working fine !

so i am confused, why git is not taking the username !!!!
i checked the `git config --local --list`, nothing is set locally !!!
only global git config has the user.name and user.email !!!

Answer (score 2):

The `user.name` and `user.email` configurations [have no effect](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-WhatshouldIputincodeusernamecode) on authentication in any way.  They affect only the personal name and email address you put in a commit or tag.

If it works for you to put the username in the push URL, then do that: that's the simplest, easiest way to make this work.  Every user using a site such as GitHub or GitLab must put the username (`git`) in the URL, so doing so shouldn't be a problem.  If you don't specify a username, the default is determined by OpenSSH and usually defaults to that of your local user, although it is case sensitive.  You can also override it explicitly in `~/.ssh/config` if you need to, but it's probably just easier to specify it in the URL.

Comment: thanks for the answer. As you said, I ended up adding a host config in the ~/.ssh/config :) and it works well.
infact i am using a repo manifest with multiple projects and i cant put the user-name in the shared manifest that was the issue.